# How to resolve error: freemarker.template.TemplateNotFoundException and specify custom path for load template file in FreeMarker with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, freemarker

Resolve error:

> freemarker.template.TemplateNotFoundException: Template not found for
> name . The name was interpreted by this TemplateLoader:
> LegacyDefaultFileTemplateLoader(baseDir="", canonicalBasePath=""
> Warning: The "template_loader" FreeMarker setting wasn't set
> (Configuration.setTemplateLoader), and using the default value is most
> certainly not intended and dangerous, and can be the cause of this
> error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To specify a custom path from which to read the template file in Java Spring Boot just create a method like this that creates a custom FileTemplateLoader:

```java
public freemarker.template.Configuration getConfiguration() throws IOException {
    FileTemplateLoader fileTemplateLoader = new FileTemplateLoader(new File(templateBasePath));
    freemarker.template.Configuration config = new freemarker.template.Configuration();
    config.setTemplateLoader(fileTemplateLoader);
    return config;
}
```

rather than:

```java
@Bean
public FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean freemarkerConfiguration() {
    FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean bean = new FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean();
    bean.setTemplateLoaderPath("classpath:/templates/");
    return bean;
}
```

Comment: Freemarker, when detected is auto-configured, so you shouldn't need things like this. You can specify the path in the `application.properties`.